# Playing Video on UIWebView getting Access Denied

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview

Hello Everyone i am trying to play video based on URL that i am getting through API but i am getting Error like Access Denied.

The reason why i am playing video in `UIWebView` is because Video is not the Primary feature in my Application its just for Show Tutorial to the User so i have not used `MPMoviePlayerController` but if required than i can use.

But i want know the exact reason why such Error occurs in `UIWebView`.

[image]

Any guide or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to provide your url which has access denied. one need to check it.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara This is the URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitebildz/SiteBildZ+Training+Videos+and+Documents/Quck+Overview+with+Kendall+and+Joe.mp4

Comment: i guess, to access that video or content you need to be authorized user. i am also getting same error in xml

Comment: ok BTW thanks @DipenPanchasara su chale che bhai
if u remember from LDRP gang :)

Comment: firstclass chale 6, kam karine posting (social service) lol..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below method to your **ViewController.m** :

//This method should get called when you want to add and load the webview

```
- (void)loadUIWebView
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];  
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView release]; // No need of this line if ARC is implemented in your project
}
```

Using Interface Builder-

- Add a `UIWebView` object to your interface.
- Set the "hidden" property to checked (in the "**Attributes Inspector**" window in Interface Builder). You should keep it hidden until you want to display `WebView`.
- Add the following code to your `ViewController.h`.

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
- Add the following line below the `@synthesize` in your `ViewController.m`

@synthesize webView;

- Add `[webView release];` in the dealloc method. // No need of this line if ARC is implemented in your project
  }
- Go back into IB and click on File's Owner, and connect the webView
  outlet to the webView you created.
- Add the following method.

//This method should get called when you want to add and load the webview

```
- (void)loadUIWebView
{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]]];
    self.webView.hidden = NO; 
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This does not help explain reason for error OP is mentioning in the question.